ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?' while working with MSE
I am using the auto-mpg dataset . I am giving the link of the dataset below:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/autompg-dataset
I am giving the code below:
df = pd.read_csv('data/auto-mpg.csv')

df.head()
df = df.drop('car name', axis=1)
X = df

X.head()
y = df['mpg']

y.head()
SEED = 1
# Split the data into 70% train and 30% test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=SEED)

# Instantiate a DecisionTreeRegressor dt
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=4, min_samples_leaf=0.26, random_state=SEED)

# Compute the array containing the 10-folds CV MSEs
MSE_CV_scores = - cross_val_score(dt, X_train, y_train, cv = 10,
                                    scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs = 1)

RMSE_CV = (MSE_CV_scores.mean())**(1/2)

#Error
ValueError:
All the 10 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.
Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 fits failed with the following error:

          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'


The error is caused by the presence of "?" in the data. From the Kaggle link, I noticed that the horsepower column has it.
You could replace the "?" with NaN to indicate missing value(s), and then handle these missing value(s) using appropriate techniques.

There are multiple problems in your code.
To create your features' matrix X you should not modify the whole dataset and set the variable equal to it but you should:

Identify those fields (features) that actually influence the result (target).

Create X accessing only those fields.


IMPORTANT: The features' matrix should not contain the target field.
Example:
y = df['mpg']
X = df[['cylinders', 'weight', 'displacement', 'acceleration', 'model year', 'origin']]

I purposely avoided to put the horsepower field because it is the one giving you problems since it contains strings: '?'. You could solve this problem by deleting the inconsistent rows or setting them equal to a standard value.
Other than this, during the testing of your code, I encountered one more problem. The last row RMSE_CV = (MSE_CV_scores.mean())**(1/2) is trying to calculate the square root of a negative value and is giving me this error: <ipython-input-52-7db3997c77e2>:27: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar power RMSE_CV = (MSE_CV_scores.mean())**(1/2).

The negative value is due to the scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error' setting, as its name clearly implies.
